# Proof relevant relation

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Let $$ac : \left( \prod_{(x:A)}\sum_{(y:B)}R(x,y) \right) \rightarrow\left( \sum_{(f : A \rightarrow B)}\prod_{(x:A)}R(x,f(x)) \right)$$
defined by $$ac(g) :\equiv \Big( \lambda x.pr_1(g(x)), \lambda x.pr_2(g(x)) \Big)$$
where $g : \prod_{(x:A)}\sum_{(y:B)}R(x,y)$. So far so good.

---

Then, my book suggests a proof to verify that this is well-typed. However, I do not understand the following statement :

> Moreover the type $\prod_{x:A}R(x, pr_1(g(x)))$ is the result of applying the type family $\lambda f.\prod_{(x:A)}R(x, f(x))$ being summed over in the codomain of $\textit{ac}$ to the function $\lambda x.pr_1(g(x))$ $$\prod_{(x:A)}R(x, pr_1(g(x))) \equiv \left( \lambda f.\prod_{(x:A)}R(x,f(x)) \right)\Big( \lambda x.pr_1(g(x)) \Big)$$

What does the notation $(\dots)(\dots)$ mean here ?

> Thus we have $$\Big( \lambda x.pr_1(g(x)), \lambda x.pr_2(g(x)) \Big) :\ \sum_{(f : A \rightarrow B)}\prod_{(x:A)}R(x,f(x))$$

How exactly do we come up with this ?

Comment: in (...)(...) the first is the function and in the second parentheses they put its argument.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжев Then why don't we just write $\lambda x.\prod_{(x:A)}R(x, pr_1(g(x)))$ ?

Comment: Why would they? This does not even make any sense: you bind $x$ twice.

Comment: Yeah you're right sorry. I understand that $\lambda x.pr_2(g(x)) : \left( \lambda f.\prod_{(x:A)} R(x,f(x)) \right) \Big( \lambda x.pr_1(g(x)) \Big)$ but why do we omit $\Big( \lambda x.pr_1(g(x)) \Big)$ in the last statement ?

Comment: Oh actually it makes sense since $\lambda x.pr_1(g(x)) \equiv f$

Comment: Just curious: what does all this have to do with proof relevance?